# Fetch не записывает данные в переменную

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, практикуюсь с получением данных с помощью fetch, написал простой скрипт, но полученные данные не записываются в переменную, моя переменная как была undefined, так и остается undefined.

```
let weather

fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ukhta&units=metric&appid=9799b689494d4d8ada4a1d65cad8eb5e`)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => weather = data)

console.log(weather)
```

> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не много переписал твой код, попробуй так.
Советую не много изучить как работает Promise

```js
(async () => {

  let weather = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ukhta&units=metric&appid=9799b689494d4d8ada4a1d65cad8eb5e`)
      .then(data => data.json());

  console.log(weather)

})().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Исправьте опечатки в вопросе. Для этого нажмите кнопку "Править" снизу от ответа.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!